# emacs: How do I disable relative indent

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am using emacs to do a variety of text editing.

I want to DISABLE relative-indent in text mode, and I just want straight simple tab to be always 8 spaces and I do not want the tab to stop at a point under previous non-blank line. Tab is tab, just move the cursor 8 spaces; that simple.

I do not want to change tab width; I am not talking about electric indent; I am not talking about inserting a tab char; I am not an emacs-source-code programmer, and I have no time for reprogramming emacs. I have tried nearly all the advices, e.g., setting tab stops, and I still cannot easily turn OFF relative indent.

I just want simple tab to fill 8 spaces regardless or the previous line; just like the tab in microsoft Notepad or Wordpad. Why is it so hard to turn off relative indent ?

The links reflexively and robotically provided by the moderator in response to my question are not helpful in turning OFF relative indent and completely misunderstood what I want to do.

Thanks

=============

and after hours of struggle, I am providing answers to myself:

The most annoying thing is the very simple thing and you cannot find the answer. Finally, I have read this, but I have not tried it out yet: " M-x local-set-key  tab-to-tab-stop Permanently use tab-to-tab-stop to control TAB behavior: (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop); # in every mode OR (define-key text-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop); # only in text-mode

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23748046/113848

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18970809/113848

Comment: The most annoying thing is the very simple thing and you cannot find the answer. Finally, I have read this, but I have not tried it out yet: " M-x local-set-key<RET> <TAB> tab-to-tab-stop  Permanently use tab-to-tab-stop to control TAB behavior:    (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop);           # in every mode
    OR
    (define-key text-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop); # only in text-mode